# Thinking Sphinx: search across multiple models: best practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to add a jquery autocomplete with categories.
The request will search across multiples models (Forum topics, news, users...) with Thinking Sphinx

So in controller, I think it will look like that

```
def autocomplete
 @news = Actu.search(params[:term]).map {|g| {:label => g.title, :category => "Actualités", :id => g.id}}
 @topics = Topic.search(params[:term]).map {|g| {:label => g.title, :category => "Topics", :id => g.id}}
 @anotherModel = ...

 respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render :json => @news+@topics+@anotherModel }
 end
end
```

That working, but what do you think about these practice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search across all indexed models in your application:

```
ThinkingSphinx.search(params[:term])
```

Then you can define for each model method, say `autocomplete_json`, that returns hash.

So, your action

```
def autocomplete
  render :json => ThinkingSphinx.search(params[:term]).map(&:autocomplete_json)
end
```

Comment: Why do you think so? It's user-crafted method.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this awesome syntax

```
ThinkingSphinx.search 'pancakes', :classes => [Article, Comment]
```

Read more at http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html

Comment: Oh, I have read this page many times... but I don't seeing the "Application-Wide Search" section. Thanks !